# VBA Delete Visible Rows Very Slow w/ large database

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I am not clear as to why this Delete command is so slow in VBA, when the database is large. The database has about 80,000 records and the delete command bellow takes about 5 minutes to run.

```
'Deletes all Card interactions
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1" & LastRowEx).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*card*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1" & LastRowEx).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Any idea why this is so slow and how I can speed it up? I have to do this a few times for other fields in the database and it is extending the run time quit a bit. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: try using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before doing all the tasks on your worskheets

Comment: It seems like this may not be what you want:  ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H1" & LastRowEx).  Is there a reason that you have a one after the H?  That is going to add a one to the beginning of whatever value LastRowEx has.  So e.g., if LastRowEx is 80,000, your code will add a 1 to the beginning and make your range 180,000 rows.

Comment: Consider using an *actual* database. Excel isn't a database, it works great with *spreadsheet*, much less so as a "poor man's database".

Comment: Also, how to you declare `LastRowEx`? Perhaps that can be tweaked? Also, is the `_` in this accidental, `.SpecialCells _(xlCellTypeVisible)`? Or do you indeed have the `(xlCellTypeVisible)` on a new line?

Comment: Ah! It was the 1 after the H! I had copied that line from someone elses code and it ran so I figured it was right. Thanks so much for the help.